# Entity Framework Core 7 with Postgres and utc values

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I have an EF Core model with attributes such as

```
public DateTime CreatedUtc
```

I set this to `DateTime.UtcNow` when I add entities. I noticed that when this is deployed to a Postgres database in CA, it changes it to California time, and the database column is a "Timestamp with timezone".

The same model is also deployed to SQLite databases, and it is stored and consumed in various timezones.

How can I configure my EF Core model to just save the UTC value?